# Any way to not be required to use full path to file in Xcode? [C/C++]

Tags: c++, c, xcode

In Xcode, whenever I want to use a file (in C or C++ specifically), I have to specify the full path to the file, whereas with gcc or g++, I do not have to if it is in the same directory as the code referencing it.

Is there a reason to why this is? And if so, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: You can call chdir() to change the current working directory to where you want to start. Then you don't need to specify the fullpath.

Comment: Can you tell more how you "use" a file? There are countless ways how you can use files in Xcode - and I've never had to specify a path manually. If you have a console app, and your program tries to open a file, you need to specify the absolute path, or a relative path which is then dependent on the environment and the current working directory. Getting this path requires system dependent functions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I meant using `std::ifstream` or `std::ofstream` on a file.

Comment: 1. To the right of your Run button on the top left side of the toolbar is the Active Scheme drop-list. Click it once. 2. Select "Edit Scheme" 3. Select the "Run" target in the left-side list. 4. Select the "Options" tab in the right-hand pane. 5. Check the "Use Custom Working Directory" checkbox. 6. Fill in the full path to the working directory you want your program to use at startup from the IDE (I use my home user directory). Thats it.

Comment: Unfortunately the "Use Custom Working Directory" checkbox doesn't seem to work in Xcode 5.0.1. At least according to "(lldb) script import os; print os.getcwd()" which prints "/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that "XCode" doesn't accept a relative path. The problem is that your code has a different current working directory than you think. You can, as the comment says, use `chdir` to get to a place where your file is, or use a relative path that takes into account the currend working directory (you can use `getcwd()` to get the current working directory).

When you are using `gcc` or `g++` on the command line, *you* are in control over what directory the final application runs in.

Comment: Thank you. Would I have to call `chdir` programmatically or is there an Xcode setting?

Comment: You would use `chdir` in your program. But I would figure out what the working directory actually is and just move the files to the "right place" instead.

Comment: Is `chdir` available to Mac OSX? I'm searching for it but I only see references of it to the Win32 library.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chdir.2.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that there is a concept of a "current working directory". So your
fopen()s and such start from there. In unix, from a shell, the CWD is your current
directory. The same for starting a command line tool from a Terminal window in
MacOS. But, when you start from Xcode, or launch an App, the CWD is somewhere else.

Like I said in my comment, you can call `chdir()` to change the current working directory to where you want to start. Then you don't need to specify the fullpath.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the little folder icon above the Navigator, i.e., the panel at the left of the XCode window. This should let you see what files and products are part of your project. There is a folder that says "Products." Expand that folder by clicking on the triangle to its left. You will see your executable (the icon looks like a terminal window). Control-click on that and choose "Reveal in Finder" to open the folder that actually contains the executable. That's the directory you need your files to be in for XCode to find them the way GCC does.